# Cannot assign value to global array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, variable-assignment

I've got this code:

```
 #include <iostream>
    int tabela[1];
    tabela[0] = 1;
    int main(){
        std::cout << tabela[0];
        std::cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
```

and it doesn't want to work. My compiler says " "tabela" doesn't name a type".
However if I do this:

```
#include <iostream>
int tabela[1];
int main(){
    tabela[0] = 1;
    std::cout << tabela[0];
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

It works. Can sb explain me why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's simply not valid C++. In global scope you can only declare or initialize types and variables, not assign them.

Comment: Can't explain it better than what dolan already said

Comment: I don't know something so i got minus. Thanks everybody for your answers. When i changed array to int i got the same problem, so now i know why. Thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the outermost level, a C++ file is a sequence of declarations. `tabela[0] = 1;` is not a declaration - it's a statement (in particular an expression-statement). A function body, however, is a sequence of statements, so it's fine to put this line inside the body of `main` (or any other function).

<sub>Some statements *are* declarations (called declaration-statements), but in general they're not.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

for it to be valid C++, you can only initialize variables in global, you can't assign them there.

edit: comments beat me to it. props